# JWT token with role. ASP.NET Core & AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity

I have working example of JWT Token. It is work good and when I put this token to storage in angularJS I can go to api controller with attribute [Authorize]. But when I generate token with role, I cant go to attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]. As I know I role save in token and I need`t to change a header of request to api. My code below

```
 public class AuthOptions
{
public const string ISSUER = "MyAuthServer"; 
public const string AUDIENCE = "http://localhost:51489/"; 
const string KEY = "mysupersecret_secretkey!123";   
public const int LIFETIME = 60; 
public static SymmetricSecurityKey GetSymmetricSecurityKey()
{
    return new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(KEY));
}

}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("login")]
public async Task Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel model)
{
    var identity = await GetIdentity(model.Email, model.Password);
    if (identity == null)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 400;
        await Response.WriteAsync("Invalid username or password.");
        return;
    }

    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: AuthOptions.ISSUER,
            audience: AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
            notBefore: now,
            claims: identity.Claims,
            expires: now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(AuthOptions.LIFETIME)),
            signingCredentials: new 
     SigningCredentials(AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(), 
 SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
    var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

    var response = new
    {
        access_token = encodedJwt,
        username = identity.Name,
    };


    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    await Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, new 
JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented }));
    return;
}

 private async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GetIdentity(string username, string 
 password)
{

    var user = _db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == username);

    if (user != null)
    {

        var checkPass = _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);

        if (!checkPass.Result)
            return null;

        var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        string role = userRoles[0];

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, role)
        };
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity =
        new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Token", ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType,
            ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
        return claimsIdentity;
    }


    return null;
}
```

Startup

```
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = 
                newTokenValidationParameters
                {

                    ValidateIssuer = true,

                    ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.ISSUER,


                    ValidateAudience = true,

                    ValidAudience = AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,

                    ValidateLifetime = true,


                    IssuerSigningKey =AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),

                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                };
            });
```

Put to storage with angularJS $cookies

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + 
response.data.access_token;
```

With this atribute is working

```
[Authorize]
```

With this atribute not working

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Comment: I fail to reproduce your issue, try trouble shot with steps below:1. log the `access_toekn` in the client side, and decode it to see whether it contains `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`, 2. check the http request in web browser, whether it append `Authorization` with the right token in the request. A demo which could reproduce your issue would be helpful.

Comment: Can you check your jwt access token with jwt.io website. Check that the claim for the role exists.

Comment: Show me your Startup.cs configuration. Make sure that you have map the policy in authorization service. `services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("TrainedStaffOnly",
            policy => policy.RequireClaim("CompletedBasicTraining"));
    });`

Comment: prntscr.com/mspes4

Answer (score 0):

You are storing your Role as a claim in the token.

You will need to create a policy that works of the role claim that you have assigned to your token.

Create a policy in your `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Role", "Admin"));
});
```

Then you can use this authorization attribute `[Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]`

Comment: In my startup I have this http://prntscr.com/mspes4 but it did  ot help, maybe I need to write it anothe case